# How to validate a form using HTML5 and CSS

Tags: html, css

I coded a form that can post information to another page where it is processed. I wanted to  ask users if there are options that were not selected. My form looks like this:

```
<form action="answers-of-brain-teaser-questions.php" method="post">
<div>
<div>Question 1</div>
<input name="q1" type="radio" value="1">A. 1
<br />
<input name="q1" type="radio" value="2">B. 4
<br />
<input name="q1" type="radio" value="3">C. 3
<br />
<input name="q1" type="radio" value="4">D. 2
</div>
<div>
<div id="question">Question 2</div>
<input name="q2" type="radio" value="5">A. 1
<br />
<input name="q2" type="radio" value="6">B. 2
<br />
<input name="q2" type="radio" value="7">C. 3
<br />
<input name="q2" type="radio" value="8">D. 4
</div>
</form>
```

How can I show users a message if some radio buttons are clicked. I only want to show a message if a question has no selected answer (no radio button is selected). For example, if no option is selected for question 2.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is with the built-in HTML5 attribute called ***required*** which tells the user that he has left a field (in our case the radio button).
An example how to use it:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="exampleForm" action="#" method="get">
            <input name="q1" type="radio" required="required" value="4">test<br />
            <input name="q1" type="radio" required="required" value="4">test<br />
            <input name="q1" type="radio" required="required" value="4">test<br />
            <input name="sform" type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're worried about browser compatability w/ HTML5, you could always do a quick jQuery check (pseudo): 

if (!$('input[@name="q1"]:checked'))
{
    //val error
}

Comment: That's right! But only Safari doesn't support it at the moment.

Comment: Hmm... i tested it and doesn't work in IE9, but W3Schools says that only Safari doesn't support the attribute.

Comment: W3Schools only refers to the newest versions of browsers and also explicitly states that this is supported in IE10 only.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no access to JQuery and want to support browsers not supporting `required`, you can use something like this:

```
var names = new Array("q1", "q2");
var notSelected = new Array();
var checked = "";
for(var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
    var current = getElementsByName(names[i]);
    for(var j = 0; j < current.length; ++j) {
        if(current[j].checked) {
            checked = names[i];
        }
    }
    if(names[i] !== checked)
        notSelected.push(names[i]);
}
if(notSelected.length>0)
    alert("You have to select the following radiogroups: "+notSelected.join(", "));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate it via jquery it will go like-
//in script add jquery-min.js

```
function validate(){
  if($("input[name=q2]:checked").length > 0) {
   //Is Valid
  }
}
<form action="answers-of-brain-teaser-questions.php" method="post" onsubmit="validate()">
<div>
<div>Question 1</div>
<input name="q1" type="radio" value="1">A. 1
<br />
<input name="q1" type="radio" value="2">B. 4
<br />
<input name="q1" type="radio" value="3">C. 3
<br />
<input name="q1" type="radio" value="4">D. 2
</div>
<div>
<div id="question">Question 2</div>
<input name="q2" type="radio" value="5">A. 1
<br />
<input name="q2" type="radio" value="6">B. 2
<br />
<input name="q2" type="radio" value="7">C. 3
<br />
<input name="q2" type="radio" value="8">D. 4
</div>
</form>
```

And if you want to do it in php page-
then check it via-

```
if(!isset($_POST['q2'})){
//your msg to user
}
```